# I'm looking for a better way to figure out the root of this ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid problem I'm having

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, activerecord

I'm very new to coding so please bare with me being a noob. Ive got a wallpaper calculator that works fine in both development and production environments on localhost:3000, but when I deploy the site the calculator doesn't load up, the only log i can see because im not running it locally is this which im getting from the logs on render where im hosting my app:

```
Sep 29 10:56:54 PM  I, [2023-09-29T21:56:54.147139 #84]  INFO -- : [7596173b-1186-4b09-b9aa-135e556df481] Started GET "/wallpaper" for 172.71.151.43 at 2023-09-29 21:56:54 +0000
Sep 29 10:56:54 PM  I, [2023-09-29T21:56:54.148943 #84]  INFO -- : [7596173b-1186-4b09-b9aa-135e556df481] Processing by WallpaperCalcController#calculator as HTML
Sep 29 10:56:54 PM  I, [2023-09-29T21:56:54.156343 #84]  INFO -- : [7596173b-1186-4b09-b9aa-135e556df481] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
Sep 29 10:56:54 PM  F, [2023-09-29T21:56:54.157544 #84] FATAL -- : [7596173b-1186-4b09-b9aa-135e556df481]
Sep 29 10:56:54 PM  F, [2023-09-29T21:56:54.157874 #84] FATAL -- : [7596173b-1186-4b09-b9aa-135e556df481] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'wallpaper_calcs'):
Sep 29 10:56:54 PM  F, [2023-09-29T21:56:54.158084 #84] FATAL -- : [7596173b-1186-4b09-b9aa-135e556df481]
Sep 29 10:56:54 PM  F, [2023-09-29T21:56:54.158323 #84] FATAL -- : [7596173b-1186-4b09-b9aa-135e556df481] app/controllers/wallpaper_calc_controller.rb:4:in `calculator'
```

there doesn't seem to be a direct issue with the database or the routes, the wallpaper_calcs table exists and can be accessed in the console, both the migration and schema indicate that the table wallpaper_calcs exists. I can submit a calculation in both development and production environments and the database is updated in both development.sqlite3 and production.sqlite3 respectively, however, the error "Could not find table 'wallpaper_calcs'" persists on the live website, I should mention the rest of the site works fine, the error only appears when I try to access the page the calculator is on.

1. Ensured Migrations Are Run:
   Ensured that I've run migrations on the production database.
2. Database Configuration:
   Checked database configuration in config/database.yml file to ensure that the production environment is connecting to the intended database.
3. Database Connection:
   Ensured that the deployed application has the correct database connection configurations and has the necessary permissions to read and write to the database.
4. Checked File Path:
   Ensured that the path to the production.sqlite3 file is correct and that the file is accessible.
5. Checked File Permissions:
   Ensured that the Rails application has permission to read and write to the production.sqlite3 file.
6. Inspected Migrations/schema.rb:
   Double-checked migrations to ensure that they are correctly defining the 'wallpaper_calcs' table.
7. Checked Model Definition:
   Ensured that the model WallpaperCalc is correctly defined and there is no typo or issue in the model file.
8. Checked Controller Action:
   Inspected the calculator action in the WallpaperCalcController as pointed out in the error log. Seems it’s trying to access the 'wallpaper_calcs' table correctly given I'm getting the results in both database files.
9. Checked Dependencies:
   Checked if all gems and dependencies are installed.
10. Changed Start Command Settings In Render:
    from `bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}`
    to `bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-production}`
11. Checked production.log For Error Messages:
    Looked into the production.log to identify the specific error messages and stack traces to pinpoint the issue but getting no errors at all, the only log I'm able to get errors from is this one I've posted from Render.

I have possibly tried some other fixes along the way that I can't think of right now but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Show, don't tell.

Comment: Are you really using SQLite in production? Also a heads up - `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]` will override any settings provided in the `database.yml` file and is automatically set on platforms like Heroku.

Comment: Also the best way to do a sanity check here would be to just use `rails db` which launches the database adapter specific DB client. In the SQlite cli you can use the command `.tables` to list the database tables. You can also run a `select * from schema_migrations;` and check the last version against the migrations that you have run in development.

Comment: Yeah I'm a total noob I'll admit I didn't really appreciate the differences between SQLite and Postgres, but now I do and appreciate why the problem was happening in the first place, it's because of render not being able to use SQLite without using a disk, and as you mention it's not really meant for production anyway. I fixed the problem by removing the database entirely since it wasn't needed for the calculator and will update in future to post gres, it's the first thing I've ever coded and the whole project is a continuous learning experience!